# How to use Google Inspect and Edit Pages and Styles?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I am new at programming websites in wordpress and would like to know how I can use the Google Inspect and Edit Pages and Styles.

Example:
I have images on a website footer. These images are obtained placed there from a arbitrary file.

Question:
How can i via the Google tool obtain which arbitrary file these images are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F12 and find for your element, under you will see css and can manipulate with it. Also you can change,[image] add, remove elements.

Comment: Can you guide me where I can find this "css", maybe an image to describe that in your OP?

Comment: Great, thank you. If I want to know which css file this can be obtained from, do I just hover over the right field?

Comment: When you hover over the div in html you will see which div is it on page. Just try it out.

Comment: Sorry Filip, but I can't find this "div" you are talking about?

Comment: Div is an element like span img and others.